# File dialog opens up multiple times when clicked more than once AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am referring to the [**link**](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/), for creating a file-upload functionality using AngularJS.

When I click on the '*Choose file*', more than once and still when the dialog isn't open, even once, after selecting the *file*, when the dialog has opened up for the first-time, I could still see the multiple dialog opening up one after the other.

How to solve this issue?

Let me know about it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is much you can do about it, other than to modify the source code yourself, and use the modified version. The behavior you describe can be easily reproduced on the page you linked. However, what is the big deal, really? You can only select one file at a time, even though the window opens many times.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle, what modified version one can use? Please elaborate yourself. Although, one can select only once, it's not a good idea to select the same file again and again, if one has pressed the button 10 time. Moreover, from the user's end perspective, it's not a good behavior.

Comment: You must modify the source code yourself to get different behavior. That's making a big assumption that the behavior you want is even possible to achieve. The browser might be designed in such a way that there is no modification that you can make to ng-file-upload that would make a difference. It seems like a lot of work for something so small.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle, could you help me with a sample ...

Comment: Can you tell us AngularJS version and what browser have you tested ?

Comment: @HéctorLeón, I am using AngularJS 1.5 and tested out in Chrome

Comment: @Shashank is a really weird behavior because i'm using now AngularJS 1.5.7 in Chrome and Chrome Canary. and i'm trying to click multiple times in the Choose file button, but is opening only once, just happening with the input file of your link :S

Comment: @HéctorLeón, r u using the same components as mentioned in the link?

Comment: nono i tried to told u ( sorry @Shashank by my poor english ) only happens with that component, with the standard input works as expected

Comment: @HéctorLeón, yeah got u...do you have any solution for it?

Comment: @Shashank I tried yesterday all the params of the components but cannot find the problem :S srr

Comment: this doesnt happen in FireFox.

Comment: @techie_28, the main target in Chrome itself. Moreover, if one gives a solution, it should ideally behave well in Chrome and FF. If it works well in Chrome, it's more than sufficient.

Comment: Please do remember to create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions on the Stack Overflow website that do not rely on an external resource. If that link dies, this question could become meaningless to future viewers. [Please also refer to this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed)

Comment: @Draken, yeah thankx, that would be really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using **ng-model** in your button. Instead of **ng-model** you have to *write your own custom* **directive**. For file input avoid using a button. The better way is to use a **file input** tag as shown below:

Angularjs:

```
    myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) { 
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;
        element.bind('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
    }
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
    <input id="chooseFile" type="file" file-model="file" name="Attachment" multiple/>
```

Hopefully, this will work out.

Comment: Although, I am unable to replicate the reported issue by creating a demo, but when I incorporate the same in my application, I could still replicate it.

Comment: @Shashank, Can you post your edited code?

Answer (score 4):

I have updated a sample from [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) with using AngularJS 1.5.1 as the following code. Can you try and let me know the result ?

```js
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
      data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
    });

    file.upload.then(function (response) {
      $timeout(function () {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
    }, function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
      // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
    }
}]);
```

```css
.thumb {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}

form .progress {
    line-height: 15px;
}
}

.progress {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px groove #CCC;
}

.progress div {
    font-size: smaller;
    background: orange;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>



<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Upload on form submit</legend>
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="username" size="31" required>
      <i ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">*required</i>
      <br>Photo:
      <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
             accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
             ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
      <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
      <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
          {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
      <img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb"> <button ng-click="picFile = null" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>
      <br>
      <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" 
              ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
      <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" 
            ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
      </span>
      <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
      <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I can still replicate the issue in your example.

Comment: Have you tried tested on Firefox and IE ?

Comment: The link that I have included in the question, itself doesn't has the issue in FF. Although, I didn't tried in IE, but the main browser in which I am targeting is Chrome itself. If it works in Chrome, it's more than sufficient.

Comment: Are you Visual Studio for code editor with BrowserLink?

Comment: not necessary. But I use Sublime text editor.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with your Js file.Try using forEach looping constraint while uploading a new file which would recursively be called every time on a new upload.
Example :

```
    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
            data: {file: file}
        });`
```

Please refer to this JsFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/

Comment: I am using for a single file itself. Anyways, the issue still persists in your demo.

Comment: That's not my demo that's from the official documentation of the ng-fileupload github.